# How to make listview selected item selectable?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am implementing an endless ListView (like in the Facebook app). I want to make item as select(temporarily show background as grey) which I select. when I click on listview, nothing happens(not shown as grey). I tried setting `android:focusable="false"` and `android:cickable="false"` for  my List view contents. But I didn't notice any chanage What is my fault? Any One help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the clicked option as highlighted. Don't put clicklistener to convetview. Use

```
      ListView.SetOnclicklistener(..){
        ...
      }
```

That is best one  to remove the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using a selector which you can set as the background of your list item.

drawable/background_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/default_color" /> 
</selector>
```

layout/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_list_item"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/someGreyColor" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/anyColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/backgrounColor"/>

</selector>
```